# How to integrate OSM tiles

Tags: openstreetmap

I am developing an app  in which i want offline map so am using osmdroid and slf4j libs.I have map tiles which i get using the Mobile Atlas Creator. How to integrate those tiles in java code ?

MainActvity is:

```
package com.example.osmofflinemap;

import org.osmdroid.DefaultResourceProxyImpl;
import org.osmdroid.ResourceProxy;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.ScaleBarOverlay;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.SimpleLocationOverlay;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;
    private ScaleBarOverlay mScaleBarOverlay;
    private SimpleLocationOverlay mMyLocationOverlay;
     MyItemizedOverlay myItemizedOverlay = null;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
           MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
            map.setTileSource(new XYTileSource("MapQuest",
                ResourceProxy.string.mapquest_osm, 0, 18, 256, ".jpg", new String[] {
                    "/sdcard/osmdroid/MapQuest/4/10/6",
                    "/sdcard/osmdroid/MapQuest/4/10/7",
                    "/sdcard/osmdroid/MapQuest/4/11/6",
                    "/sdcard/osmdroid/MapQuest/4/11/7"}));
            map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
            map.setUseDataConnection(false); //optional, but a good way to prevent loading from the network and test your zip loading. 
            IMapController mapController = map.getController();
            mapController.setZoom(4);
            GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(18.533333, 73.866667);
            mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
        }

}
```

Comment: Did you already try to replace the MapQuest tile source with Mobile Atlas Creator? Does Mobile Atlas Creator use the same [tile names and directory structure](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) as OSM?

Comment: Yes, there is same ties and directory structure as OSM  for  Mobile Atlas Creator .Is there any titorial or demo for the same ?

Comment: If the directory structure is the same then it should be sufficient to add it via the `XYTileSource`. You are already using it in your code for specifying the path to the MapQuest tiles.